# Can I change screen orientation manually?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a book reader app using Flutter and I need a button that whenever it is pressed it automatically rotates screen orientation into landscape mode as it is in YouTube.

Is there a such option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SystemChrome class for setting the orientation.

Import the following

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Landscape Right"),
              onPressed: (){
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
            });

RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Landscape Left"),
              onPressed: (){
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
            });
```

#### References

1. [Device Orientation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/DeviceOrientation-class.html)
2. [how-to-change-screen-orientation-in-flutter](https://dev.to/mightytechno/how-to-change-screen-orientation-in-flutter-32c1)

Answer (score 1):

Just call the following function

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,]);
```

Possible values for DeviceOrientation are

```
enum DeviceOrientation {
  /// If the device shows its boot logo in portrait, then the boot logo is shown
  /// in [portraitUp]. Otherwise, the device shows its boot logo in landscape
  /// and this orientation is obtained by rotating the device 90 degrees
  /// clockwise from its boot orientation.
  portraitUp,

  /// The orientation that is 90 degrees clockwise from [portraitUp].
  ///
  /// If the device shows its boot logo in landscape, then the boot logo is
  /// shown in [landscapeLeft].
  landscapeLeft,

  /// The orientation that is 180 degrees from [portraitUp].
  portraitDown,

  /// The orientation that is 90 degrees counterclockwise from [portraitUp].
  landscapeRight,
}
```